# problem with synchronous fetching data in Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am working with 4 Axios.get statements, which are provided to fetch data from 4 different sources at once. There is no problem to fetch them in first fetching try - services are working and showing results properly. As I understand my problem is that when I'm trying to rewrite result by using other axios.get it renders first, then fetches data.

Below is code for two Axios.gets, where getCashboxBonusNDS() causing error if it comes second, after getCashboxuserBonusNDS(). And switch statement that changes Api service on change

```
getCashboxuserBonusNDS = (dateFrom, dateTo, client) => {
    Axios.get('/api/report/sales/ndscashboxuser', {
        params: { dateFrom, dateTo, client }
    }).then(res => res.data)
        .then((salesResultNDS) => {
            this.setState({ salesResultNDS, isLoading: false });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
};

getCashboxBonusNDS = (dateFrom, dateTo, client) => {
    Axios.get('/api/report/sales/ndscashbox', {
        params: { dateFrom, dateTo, client }
    }).then(res => res.data)
        .then((salesNDS) => {

            const temp = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(salesNDS, 'point'), list => list.map(bs => _.omit(bs, 'point')));

            const salesResultNDS = Object.keys(temp).map(key => {
                return {
                    point: key,
                    cashboxesNDS: temp[key]
                }
            });
            this.setState({ salesResultNDS, cashboxSalesResultNDS: salesNDS, isLoading: false });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
};

 switch (filter.value) {
        case 'cashboxFiz': {

            if(filterType.value==='cashbox'){
                this.getCashboxBonus(dateFrom, dateTo, "fiz");
                this.getCashboxBonusNDS(dateFrom, dateTo, "fiz")
            }else{
                this.getCashboxuserBonus(dateFrom, dateTo, "fiz");
                this.getCashboxuserBonusNDS(dateFrom, dateTo, "fiz")
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'cashboxJur': {

            if(filterType.value==='cashbox'){
                this.getCashboxBonus(dateFrom, dateTo, "jur");
                this.getCashboxBonusNDS(dateFrom, dateTo, "jur")
            }else{
                this.getCashboxuserBonus(dateFrom, dateTo, "jur");
                this.getCashboxuserBonusNDS(dateFrom, dateTo, "jur")
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
            console.log("Error: filter not detected")
    }
```

The only error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to chain together promises, to ensure specific requests are always executed in order (synchronous). I've included an example below.

```
const get = (endpoint = '/', params = {}) => {
  // return axios promise
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: apiHost + endpoint,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token ' + this.state.token },
    params: params,
  });
};

get('/api/some-endpoint/')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    //return next promise
    return get('/api/another-endpoint/');
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    // return next promise
    return get('/api/yet-endpoint');
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    // return next promise
    return get('/api/last-endpoint/');
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    // finished, no more promises left in the chain
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error getting data', error);
  });
```

Comment: Is it necessary to include url and headers in get()?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. Your usage is correct. This link explains the different ways to call Axios methods: https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index